# React JS this.state is undefined: Cannot read property 'components' of undefined, where components is a state of the "Board" Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a React app in which I play with creating, removing and editing components (more exactly changing their text). I have a basic Component, called 'MyComponent', and a 'Board' component, which contains all the 'MyComponent's created in an array called 'components', which is a state in the 'Board'. Removing and adding a new component works perfectly.

The idea behind editing is that when the user clicks the "Edit" button, the state "Editing" changes to true, and a textarea is displayed so the user can type the new text, and when he wants to click save, the "Editing" state goes back to false, thus going back to the view of a div with the name. (the name should also be updated).

Error name: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'components' of undefined.

Link to the code: https://github.com/AndreiEneCristian/ReactComponents/blob/master/EventHandl2.html

For a reason I do not know, whenever I try to save an edited component, thus changing its text and going back to the renderNormal function in "MyComponent", the browser gives me the error "Cannot read property 'components' (which is a state) of undefined". I tried to print some lines in the console, for debugging reasons, the data is correctly handled (meaning the state of 'MyComponent' successfully changes to false, the newText is saved in the "newText" variable) but it crashes because "this.state" is undefined.

The console error points me to this line: "var arr = this.state.components;" in the function:

```
updateComponent: function(newText, i) {
        console.log(this.state);
        var arr = this.state.components;
        arr[i] = newText;
        this.setState({components: arr});
        },
```

Note: this.state is undefined, which is the issue behind it all. How can I solve this?

Comment: `updateComponentText={this.updateComponent.bind(this)}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to bind the function you are passing as prop

```
<MyComponent key={i} index={i} updateComponentText={this.updateComponent.bind(this)} deleteFromBoard={this.removeComponent}>
   {text}
</MyComponent>);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved it entirely. As I am relatively new in React and do not quite grasp all there is about binding and why sometimes it is necessary, could you please suggest me a link with a tutorial that gives a proper overview on binding?

Comment: @AndreiEne binding is not React specific. It's JS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

It returns a new function with the context of this binded to the containing function (or class).

You should do `this.updateComponent = this.updateComponent.bind(this)` in the constructor of the class instead so that a new function doesn't get created every render and only once or just use es6 arrow functions: `() => {}`